# Angular Component Library Project with NGRX?

Tags: ngrx, angular-library

I've used NGRX for a few projects now and generally really like it.  But I'm struggling with whether or not to use it in my next project which will be to create an angular component library.

Is it recommended to use ngrx in angular library project types?  How would you setup the root state vs the feature state?  Would my library project's main module attach to the ngrx root store?  If so then if my library is used in a parent app that is also using ngrx would the root store's collide?

Update (More Context):

The majority of the components in the library will be typical forms of data type of stuff.  For example providing components to search, update, create and delete things across multiple applications.  We're packaging them up as a component library (and angular elements library) because they will need to be used in multiple web applications until those web applications converge into one new super web application (time line for convergence is 1+ year down the road).  The other integration path we were looking at was loading an iframe in all these client apps.

The components themselves will connect to an API layer to do all the data I/O.  Components may need to share parts of state across components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer without having the full context.

If we're speaking about a "pure" component library, I would rather not pull in any state management libraries. If the component needs some state, it should manage its state on its own.

Components using this library can always be in control of the communication with the store.

Comment: But what if you have multiple components on a page that share state. Where would you save this state and can NGRX be involved?

Comment: Funny that you ask, because I wrote a post about it yesterday. Hope it helps https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/an-experiment-using-the-global-ngrx-store-as-a-local-store

Comment: @timdeschryver would you use than 2-way binding for the component lib? and the host component will read & update the store? (just wondering if that's the way to go..) or there is any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I was responsible to develop a big library containing many coupled components and I came up to use ngrx in the library.

I assume you are familiar with ngrx and implemented the required files for a state (actions, reducers, selectors, etc).

here are my steps to use ngrx in an angular library:

step 1:
add ngrx dependencies (store, effect, entity, etc) to the main project

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^16.1.0",
"@ngrx/entity": "^16.1.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^16.1.0",
```

step 2:
add ngrx dependencies (store, effect, entity, etc) to the library project

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^16.1.0",
"@ngrx/entity": "^16.1.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^16.1.0",
```

note: update peerDependencies in the library too

step 3:
initial ngrx modules in the app.module.ts with forRoot method

```
StoreModule.forRoot({}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
```

step 4:
initial ngrx modules in the library module with forFeature method

```
StoreModule.forFeature(TEST_FEATURE_NAME,{testPage: testPageReducer}),
EffectsModule.forFeature([]), // no effects for now
```